# sleuth traceId is not propagated using WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have this endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("processor")
public Flux<String> getSomeStringsAndProcessThem() {
    log.info("processing some strings");
    return WebClient.create().get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("localhost:8083/emitter")
                    .build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(String.class)
            .map(v -> {
                log.info("In map operator, processing {} ", v);
                return switch (v) {
                    case "FIRST" -> "Number One\n";
                    case "THIRD" -> "Number three\n";
                    case "FIFTH" -> "Number five\n";
                    case "TENTH" -> "Number ten\n";
                    default -> v+"\n";
                };
            });
}
```

I see from the logs that the traceId from this service is not the same with the called service. (traceId is not propagated)

Any reason why WebClient is not propagating the traceId, does there need to be more config for sleuth to work with webflux ?

All sleuth config is spring default.
Using spring version

```
<version>2.7.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

and cloud

```
 <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
```

Comment: It's probably happening because you're creating your own WebClient. Try to use the pre-configured (by Spring) WebClient.Builder or WebClient instead.

Comment: hmm yea it works after I add WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder; and use it instead of just WebClient.create().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work had to autowire

`WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;`

and instead of

```
WebClient.create().get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("localhost:8083/emitter")
                .build()).retrieve
```

I used

```
return webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://"localhost:8083/emitter").build().get()
            .retrieve()
```